# increment totalAmount each time add product

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cart

I have a problem when I add a product the totalAmount shows me 20 I don't know why? and if I increment the totalAmount doesn't move how can I do it?

thanks

**ts.file**

```
     productList = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Louis Vuis', price: 10, qtn: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: 'shubert helmet', price: 20, qtn: 1 },
  ];

  productArray: any = [];

  totalAmount: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.totalPrice();
  }

  add(product, idx) {
    const found = this.productArray.find(
      item => JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(product)
    );
    if (found) {
      this.productArray[idx].qtn++;
    } else {
      this.productArray.push(product);
    }
  }

  totalPrice() {
    this.productList.forEach(item => {
      this.totalAmount = (item.qtn * item.price)
      console.log(this.totalAmount);
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: this.totalAmount += (item.qtn * item.price)

Answer (score 0):

```
totalAmount: number=0;
this.totalAmount += (item.qtn * item.price)
```

Comment: Mohammed, You should explain the answer not just have to post code only.

Comment: 1.You need to initialize the totalAmount =0.This you have missed in your code. Then the second line this.totalAmount += (item.qtn *item.price) what this actually means is this.totalAmount = this.totalAmount + (item.qtn *item.price). In forloop you are iterating the loop and storing the vallue in this.totalAmount.In the first loop you will get 10, and in the second loop 20.So the totalAmount is 10+20=30

Comment: No, i have told you to explain your anser after you have put code, not in comment, and it is not for me, it is explanation for user whoever sees your answer, i have got suggestion from stackoverflow to improve your answer so i have given you an advice, so there is no need to explain it in comment, rather explain it in answer itself, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhere else I feel. What you are doing is right

```
totalPrice() {
    this.productList.forEach(item => {
      this.totalAmount = (item.qtn * item.price)
      console.log(this.totalAmount);
    });
  }
```

But you are iterating the javascript object and assigning the value to total amount.

So while Iterating if you want to show price of each Item based on quantity you need to assign the value within a new key of product.

Something Like `item.total = (item.qtn * item.price);`

Incase you want to display the sum of all value in totalAmount you will need to do `this.totalAmount += (item.qtn * item.price)`

and when you add Quantity increment the quantity by 1 that you are doing , update the state and call `this.totalPrice()`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues,

1. When adding a product you are adding that in `productArray` but when calculating totalAmount you are calculating from `productList`. This will give you constant totalAmount no matter how many product you add in the productArray.
2. `this.totalAmount = (item.qtn * item.price)` will reassign the updated value into totalAmount instead of adding to the previous value. You need to write, `this.totalAmount += (item.qtn * item.price)`

From my understanding I am updating the totalPrice method. Not sure if it will help or not,

```
totalPrice() {
    this.productList.forEach(item => {
      let productIndexInProductArray = productArray.findIndex(p => p.id === item.id);
      if(productIndexInProductArray > -1) {
          this.totalAmount += (productArray[productIndexInProductArray].qtn * item.price)
          console.log(this.totalAmount);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `totalAmount` id define but not initialized
So first change is need to initialize `totalAmount`

```
totalAmount: number = 0;
```

Second change is need to do in `totalPrice` function because every time when you calculate amount that item amount set to `totalAmount` so `totalAmount` reset with every item that why you get last item amount in console. you need to add item amount in `totalAmount` like below

```
totalPrice() {
  this.productList.forEach(item => {
    this.totalAmount += (item.qtn * item.price)
    console.log(this.totalAmount);
  });
}
```